# Floating top bar

Tags: support, top-bar

Math Stack Exchange was much better before the top bar was made a floating header, always in the way of reading the site especially when scrolling up and down.

Is there a way to remove this remedial nuisance; the information the banner holds is not needed so often that it has to always be on the screen.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

Go to the [Preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) section in the Edit Profile & Settings. In the **Navigation** section, you can check the "Disable top bar stickiness" option.

This option change is applicable for all the network sites.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Preferences]